# How to remove the box shadow of the button when clicked?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How to change color of the box shadow of the prime ng button when clicked?

I change the color of the button using this lines

```
.ui-button {
  background-color: #ff6b00 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ff6b00 !important;
}
```

Comment: You mean the state when the button is clicked and before the results are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `outline: none;` on focus, as when we click it has an outline due to focus

```
.ui-button:focus { 
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Joykal Infotech. Thanks for your answer. It has no effect on the button. The blue background is appearing when clicked.

Comment: okay try this `body .ui-button:enabled:focus { box-shadow: none; )` this will work for sure !!

Answer (score 0):

use below css. thanks

```
.ui-button:focus { 
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Xenio Gracias. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it's useful for you.

```
.ui-button:active{
  box-shadow: none;
 }
```